# Curve defined by a vector

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD4Bn.png

I'm studying line integrals with a curve as a vector, but I couldn't understand the 'dr' part.

First of all: the curve isn't really a curve, it's like some points where a vector points from the origin. So this 'curve' does not really exists, rigth?

And then, when we take the integral with respect to 'dr', shouldn't we take it do ||dr|| (the magnitude of dr)? I really didn't understand, so I need some better and intuitive explanation...

Thank you so much!

Comment: Points where a set of vectors point from the origin $=$ curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, intuitively $dr$ is an infinitesimal tangent vector to the curve. If you imagine that the curve is the trajectory of some particle, then the derivative of $r$ is the velocity. If a small amount of time $dt$ passes, then you've moved through the vector $dr =r '(t)dt$.

I could stop there and pretend that this is all fine, but I won't. Elementary books insists on making people learn to think with those infinitesimals and when one needs to move to the modern approach get's really confused with questions like "but hey, the other book told it was fine to think like that! What's the problem?".

So I'll tell you the true idea. A curve in $n$-dimensional space is a map $\alpha : I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and it's tangent vector at the point $\alpha(t)$ is the derivative $\alpha'(t)$. Now, $\alpha'(t)$ already defines the tangent direction of the curve, so you don't really need that $dt$ multiplying. Now, the line integral is a measure of how much some vector field $F:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ projects on the direction of the curve.

If you recall a little about the dot product you'll soon be convinced that if we fix some point $t \in I$ and consider $\alpha(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $F(\alpha(t))\cdot \alpha'(t)$ is a good measure of how $F$ projects onto $\alpha$. We are considering the "local" direction of $\alpha$, also it'll be zero if $F$ is orthogonal to $\alpha$ and it'll be maximum if $F$ is in the direction of $\alpha$. Since this is local,  we can compute at each point and sum everything up, this will be a measure of how $F$ projects onto $\alpha$ in general (try constructing the partitions and so on, it'll be a good exercise). So we define the line integral of $F$ over $\alpha$ to be:

$$\int_\alpha F=\int_a^b F(\alpha(t))\cdot \alpha'(t)dt$$

Then, the people that love that thing of infinitesimals set $\alpha'(t)dt = dr$ and just write this as:

$$\int_a^b F\cdot dr$$

Personally I prefer the first notation because  it makes clear that you have to calculate $F$ at $\alpha(t)$, dot it with $\alpha'(t)$ and integrate this thing that will simply be a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you're integrating over a scalar field or a vector field.

Define a path $C:\vec{r}(t)$ for $a\le{t}<b$. If you are integrating over a vector field $\vec{F}(\vec{x})$, the integral is

$$\int_C\vec{F}(\vec{x})\cdot{d\vec{r}}$$

If you are integrating over a scalar field, the integral is

$$\int_C{F(\vec{x})|d\vec{r}|}$$